# Mage_Locale_en_US upgrade from 1.8.1.0 to 1.9.1.1 CONNECT ERROR

Tags: magento

Hi im about to upgrade Mage_Locale_en_US in magento connect manager after i commit changes the error goes this way

```
Checking dependencies of packages

CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.1.1 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.8.1.0
```

can someone help me about the error in this thing?Any help is muchly appreciated.TIA